# Bootstrap 4 columns hidden in small view let appear blank space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 for the first time. I want to have a website with blank columns on left and right in large view but make them disappear in small view.

[image: large view]

[image: small view]

I use this HTML structure to create the 3 columns: blank ones and the grey one we can see in the middle:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8"></div>
        <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But because of the `min-height: 1px;` which is applied to all the `.col-*` by Bootstrap, when the blank columns should be hidden, they create a little space, breaking what I want to do.

[image: the little space]

How can I do what I want? Is the way I'm using Bootstrap 4 the good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center a column (`.col`) in a row (`.row`) you can add the class `justify-content-center` (see [flex utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)) to the row:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col col-sm-12 col-md-8">Hello World</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So there is no need for empty columns to center a column.

---

Another solution would be to use the `d-*` classes ([see utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)) to hide the columns:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-none d-md-block">1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">2</div>
        <div class="col d-none d-md-block">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much.